# Adding a value into a table view (JavaFx)

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I've got an NullPointerException which occures in this file:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Controller.RocketController.addItem(RocketController.java:55)
at Controller.SurvayController.acceptButtonClicked(SurvayController.java:45)
```

Here is the part of code which probably is causing an error

RocketController:

```
    public void addItem(Aims aim)
    {
        ArrayList<Aims> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(aim);
        ObservableList<Aims> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        listView.setItems(observableList);
    }
```

This function is triggered by a button in another stage:

SurvayController:

```
@FXML
void acceptButtonClicked()
{
    Aims newAim = new Aims(directionField.getText(),comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(),distanceField.getText(),speedField.getText());
    rocketController.addItem(newAim);
    Stage stage=(Stage) speedField.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();

}
```

Have you got any ideas why i get this ?

Comment: Looks to me like your RocketController object is null, ie, it was never instantiated with RocketController mycont = new RocketController(); or it wasn't yet instantiated when the button was clicked.

Comment: @AlexR If that were true, then the `addItem` method wouldn't get invoked.

Comment: Since you haven't told us which line is actually causing the exception, I assume you don't know how to diagnose a null pointer exception. Directing to a question that explains how.

Comment: After some lecture i still have no idea what is wrong. Debbuger says that line with **ObservableList<Aims> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);** is cousing a problem

Comment: When i step over this part of code i get the information "Source not found"